# Expo (react native) how to recover firebase password

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I have a login created in expo which allows me to register and also log in but I don't know how to recover my password through email (google auth is set by email/pass) so the login is by email but I don't know how to do it that a recovery message be sent to the mail, It should be noted that I have created a modal to do that but it does not work

```
    const [showForgotPasswordModal, setShowForgotPasswordModal] = useState(false); // Nuevo estado para el modal
    <Button title="Recuperar contraseña" onPress={() => setShowForgotPasswordModal(true)} />
    
     <Modal visible={showForgotPasswordModal} transparent={true} animationType="slide">
          <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
            <View style={styles.modalContent}>
              <Text style={styles.modalTitle}>Recuperar Contraseña</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.modalInput}
                placeholder="Correo electrónico"
                value={email}
                onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
              />
              <View style={styles.modalButtonContainer}>
                <Button title="Cancelar" onPress={() => setShowForgotPasswordModal(false)} />
                <Button title="Enviar" onPress={handleForgotPassword} />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>

       async function handleForgotPassword() {
    try {
      await sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email);
      Alert.alert('Correo enviado', 'Se ha enviado un correo electrónico para restablecer tu contraseña.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error al enviar el correo electrónico:', error);
      Alert.alert('Error', 'No se pudo enviar el correo electrónico para restablecer la contraseña.');
    }
  }
```

I want you to tell me the way or the way to make it possible to recover via email, an email link or at least send the password by email (in the worst case)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication provides a method to reset the password by an email link.

Here: [sendPasswordResetEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email) method.

When you trigger this method on your app (you will need a text input to insert the email), you will receive a link at the email you just sent. Go to your email, open the link and follow the instruction to reset your password!